# how do i get mysql rows from 24-48 hours ago?

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

I have a mysql table with a datetime column. I want to fetch rows which are older than 24 hours but younger than 48 hours. Ive gone through the date time function not quite sure how to approach this or what to do in general.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Use:

```
SELECT *
  FROM YOUR_TABLE t
 WHERE t.datetime_column < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR)
   AND t.datetime_column > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 48 HOUR)
```

Comment: I was inspired to format my SQL like yours after you answered some of my SQL queries (haha, bad pun). Therefore, my (deleted) answer looks very similar to yours!

Comment: @alex: Thx, I just figure the easier it is to read--the easier it'll be to understand.  Still, you can't be doing that bad if you come to the same answer.  ...or, we both misunderstood the question =)

Comment: I also got my head around `DATE_SUB()` and its friends based on some of your answers - so thank you!

Comment: The [BETWEEN clause](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-between-clause.htm) can build a more readable sentence: `SELECT * FROM YOUR_TABLE t WHERE t.datetime_column between DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR) and DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 48 HOUR)`

Comment: @fguillen: `BETWEEN` is inclusive, meaning `<=` and `=>` -- the answer is not, because it specifically asked for records older/younger than specific values.

Comment: @OMGPonies you have a point, and this is something to be notified, but taking in consideration we are talking about _datetimes_ maybe these _extra seconds_ are not really important.